# kube-apiserver consumes a lot of memory. How can I find out the reason?

Tags: kubernetes

[image: top output]

I've noticed that kube-apiserver consumes a lot of memory resources. This leads to some terrible issues related kubernetes cluster work: in some cases, kubernetes API doesn't work.
How can I find out the reason why this process consumes a lot of memory?